# .NET Graphics what SmoothingMode?

Tags: .net, graphics

When using the Graphics object in .net what "SmoothingMode" value yields the best result HighQuality or AntiAlias??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the MSDN, they mean the same thing.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z714w2y9.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the enum values, HighQuality will provide higher quality than simply antialiasing. You should also make sure to alter PixelOffsetMode

Answer (score 0):

You Can take help from this useful Msdn Artical
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.smoothingmode.aspx